# Data Entry in registry is Not working when Use Async/Await specially in API

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, registry

```
public async Task AddValueInRegistry() {
       await Task.Run(() => {
           RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Shashi3\Stage1\Stage3", true);
           key.SetValue("Test Key", 2);
           key.Close();
       });
    }
```

Consider the above method when I run it it creates directory in registry but not data entry.
[image]

Comment: How do you use the `AddValueInRegistry` method?

Comment: Creating object of that call and calling it
await obj.AddValueInRegistry();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call `AddValueInRegistry` by using one of the following methods:

```
AddValueInRegistry().Wait();
```

or

```
public void async UpperMethod()  {
    await AddValueInRegistry();
}
```